# sql0901n non-severe system error in db2

Tags: db2

I am getting this error while taking the backup.

SQL0901N  The SQL statement failed because of a non-severe system 
error. Subsequent SQL statements can be processed.  (Reason 
"1117".)

Explanation:

An error has occurred which is due to a system error. Processing of the
SQL statement has ended for reason "" (this is in English only
and is useful only to IBM support personnel).

sqlcode: -901

sqlstate: 58004, 5UA0L

Can anyone help in this?

Comment: Anything in the db2diag.log? Are your disks ok?

Comment: other database in control center can be backup.. but i am getting error only for one database. and what to check in this log file db2diag.log

Comment: Any media error, disk problems, system issues?